If $\lim\limits_{x \to a} \frac{g(x)}{f(x)} = \lim\limits_{x \to a} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ does $\lim\limits_{x \to a} \frac{g(x)}{f(x)} = ±1$?

If $\lim\limits_{x \to a} \frac{g(x)}{f(x)} = \lim\limits_{x \to a} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$, then $\lim\limits_{x \to a} \frac{g(x)}{f(x)} = \pm1$.

Does this claim hold? I think there are 3 cases:

$\lim\limits_{x \to a} {f(x)}$ and $\lim\limits_{x \to a} {g(x)}$ is a non-zero real number.
$\lim\limits_{x \to a} {f(x)} = 0$ and $\lim\limits_{x \to a} {g(x)} = 0$.
$\lim\limits_{x \to a} {f(x)} = \pm\infty$ and $\lim\limits_{x \to a} {g(x)} = \pm\infty$.

The proof for case $1$ is trivial, but I am wondering about cases $2$ and $3$.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Don't pay attention to that bot. And don't distinguish those cases ($\lim_af$
and $\lim_ag$
could as well not exist). Hint: if $\lim_ah=\lim_a\frac1h$, then $(\lim_ah)^2=\dots$

Do not case(s) 2 and 3 follow from L'Hospital's rule ?

@AnuradhaN. No, L'Hospital's rule needs more hypothesis, and is useless here (as is the distinction of those cases, see previous comment).

Why is it $\pm1$ and not just $+1?$ When is $-1$ possible?

@AdamRubinson $f(x)=-x$ and $g(x)=\sin x$, $a=0$; or more trivial: $f=1$, $g=-1$

@AnneBauval Yes, we cannot always apply L'Hospital, and your hint makes clear the solution.

We could have $f(x) = {\rm sin}(1/x)$ and $g(x) = -{\rm sin}(1/x)$, and neither ${\rm lim}(f(x))$ nor ${\rm lim}(g(x))$ exists for $a=0$ (as in comment @AnneBauval), but the rest of the conditions are satisfied.

I think the limit of $f$ and $g$ is not important because we can know regard $h:=f/g$ be a function defined on a neighbourhood near $a$ (exclude $x=a$ prevent from messy), then the equality of limit means $\lim h=\lim\dfrac{1}{h}$. The existence of both limits already implies $\lim\dfrac{1}{h}=\dfrac{1}{\lim h}$.

Yes @AngaeMT I agree with you, but we cannot distinguish the cases as in post by OP.

Let $$h:=\frac gf.$$
If $\lim_ah=\lim_a\frac1h=\ell\in[-\infty,\infty]$, then
$$\ell^2=\left(\lim_ah\right)\left(\lim_a\frac1h\right)=\lim_a\left(h\frac1h\right)=\lim_a1=1$$
hence $\ell=\pm1$.
Edit. We applied the theorem "if $\lim_ah=\ell,\lim_ak=\ell'\in[-\infty,\infty]$ then $\lim_a(hk)=\ell\ell'$, except if the latter is an indeterminate form, i.e. if $\{\ell,\ell'\}=\{0,\pm\infty\}$".

If $\lim\limits_{x\to a}{\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}} = \pm\infty$ and $\lim\limits_{x\to a}{\frac{g(x)}{f(x)}}$ exists then $\lim\limits_{x\to a}{\frac{g(x)}{f(x)}} = 0$, so it is not consistent with $\lim\limits_{x \to a} \frac{g(x)}{f(x)} = \lim\limits_{x \to a} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$.
For the same reason, if $\lim\limits_{x\to a}{\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}} =0$, and $\lim\limits_{x\to a}{\frac{g(x)}{f(x)}}$ exists then $\lim\limits_{x\to a}{\frac{g(x)}{f(x)}}=\pm\infty$, which is not consistent either with $\lim\limits_{x \to a} \frac{g(x)}{f(x)} = \lim\limits_{x \to a} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$.
That is enough to prove that $\lim\limits_{x\to a}{\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}}$ is a real non null and finite value (say $l$) and that $\lim\limits_{x\to a}{\frac{g(x)}{f(x)}}=\frac 1 l$, so we have:
$$\left\lbrace\begin{align}&l\ne 0\\&l=\frac 1 l\end{align}\right .\implies l^2=1\implies l=\pm 1$$

Proving first that $l\ne0$ and $l\ne\pm\infty$ is useless, as explicited in my answer, where $\ell\in[-\infty,\infty]$ a priori. $\ell^2$ still makes sense if $\ell\in{-\infty,0,\infty}$.

@AnneBauval: you are right of course. But I am currently teaching mathematics to only high school students, and I would not dare have to explain them that we can extend the product operation to infinite operands...

Fair enough (+1). Another remark is that in your first sentence, the 2nd hypothesis "and $\lim\limits_{x\to a}{\frac{g(x)}{f(x)}}$ exists" is useless (it is a consequence of the 1st hypothesis $\lim\limits_{x\to a}{\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}}=\pm\infty$).
